# How can I solve this vectorial problem by repeated cross and dot products?

Tags: vectors

[image]

The problem demands repeated product formations with the vectors a, b, c and p, but I cannot figure out which all vectors I should choose after considerable analysis.

Comment: What is $[abc]$ in the brackets in the second expression? is there a dot product missing there?

Comment: Triple vector product ... I guess

Comment: Maybe $\vec a·(\vec b\text{x}\vec c)$ better.

Comment: [abc] is the scalar triple product

Answer (score 1):

If not mistaken I can deal with the first:

$$\vec p\times\vec a+(\vec p·\vec b)\vec c=\vec b\times\vec c$$

$$\require{cancel}\vec c\times(\vec p\times\vec a)+\bcancel{\vec c\times(\vec p·\vec b)\vec c}_{=0}=\vec c\times(\vec b\times\vec c)$$

$$(\vec c·\vec a)\vec p-(\vec c·\vec p)\vec a=\vec c\times(\vec b\times\vec c)$$

$$\require{cancel}(\vec c·\vec a)\vec p\times\vec a-\bcancel{(\vec c·\vec p)\vec a\times\vec a}_{=0}=(\vec c\times(\vec b\times\vec c))\times\vec a$$

$$\vec p\times\vec a=\frac{(\vec c\times(\vec b\times\vec c))}{\vec c·\vec a}\times\vec a$$

$$\vec p=\frac{(\vec c\times(\vec b\times\vec c))}{\vec c·\vec a}$$

---

The second. Let be

$$\vec C=\vec p\times\vec a+\dfrac{\left[\vec a\vec b\vec c\right]}{\vec a·\vec c}\vec c=\frac{(\vec c\times(\vec b\times\vec c))\times\vec a}{\vec c·\vec a}+\dfrac{\left[\vec a\vec b\vec c\right]}{\vec a·\vec c}\vec c=$$

$$=\frac{((\vec c·\vec c)\vec b-(\vec c·\vec c)\vec c)\times\vec a}{\vec c·\vec a}+\dfrac{\left[\vec a\vec b\vec c\right]}{\vec a·\vec c}\vec c$$

Now, prove that $\vec C·(\vec b-\vec c)=0$, so $\vec C$ is perpendicular to $\vec b-\vec c$

$$\vec C·(\vec b-\vec c)=\left(\frac{((\vec c·\vec c)\vec b-(\vec c·\vec b)\vec c)\times\vec a}{\vec c·\vec a}+\dfrac{\left[\vec a\vec b\vec c\right]}{\vec a·\vec c}\vec c\right)·(\vec b-\vec c)=$$

$$=\frac{1}{\vec a·\vec c}\left((\vec c·\vec c)\vec b\times\vec a-(\vec c·\vec b)\vec c\times\vec a+\left[\vec a\vec b\vec c\right]\vec c\right)·(\vec b-\vec c)=$$

$$=\frac{1}{\vec a·\vec c}\left((\vec c·\vec c)(\vec b\times\vec a)·(\vec b-\vec c)-(\vec c·\vec b)(\vec c\times\vec a)·(\vec b-\vec c)+\left[\vec a\vec b\vec c\right]\vec c·(\vec b-\vec c)\right)=$$

$$=\frac{1}{\vec a·\vec c}\left((\vec c·\vec c)(\vec b\times\vec a)·(-\vec c)-(\vec c·\vec b)(\vec c\times\vec a)·(\vec b)+\left[\vec a\vec b\vec c\right]\vec c·(\vec b-\vec c)\right)=\tag 1$$

$$=\frac{1}{\vec a·\vec c}\left((\vec c·\vec c)(\vec c·(\vec a\times\vec b))-(\vec c·\vec b)(\vec b·(\vec c\times\vec a))+\left[\vec a\vec b\vec c\right]\vec c·(\vec b-\vec c)\right)=\tag 2$$

$$=\frac{1}{\vec a·\vec c}\left((\vec c·\vec c)\left[\vec a\vec b\vec c\right]-(\vec c·\vec b)\left[\vec a\vec b\vec c\right]+\left[\vec a\vec b\vec c\right]\vec c·(\vec b-\vec c)\right)=\tag 3$$

$$=\frac{1}{\vec a·\vec c}\left(\left[\vec a\vec b\vec c\right]\vec c·(\vec c-\vec b)+\left[\vec a\vec b\vec c\right]\vec c·(\vec b-\vec c)\right)=0$$

$(1)$ $(\vec c·\vec c)(\vec b\times\vec a)·(\vec b-\vec c)=\bcancel{(\vec c·\vec c)(\vec b\times\vec a)·\vec b}_{=0}-(\vec c·\vec c)(\vec b\times\vec a)·\vec c$ and similarly for the second term.

$(2)$ $-\vec b\times\vec a=\vec a\times\vec b$

$(3)$ $\vec c·(\vec a\times\vec b)=\vec b·(\vec c\times\vec a)=\vec a·(\vec b\times\vec c)=\left[\vec a\vec b\vec c\right]$